# InvalidArgumentError: In[0] is not a matrix. Instead it has shape []

Tags: tensorflow, keras, regression

I'm not able to train the network using keras, getting the following error, at epoch 1, first batch:

```
InvalidArgumentError: In[0] is not a matrix. Instead it has shape []
     [[{{node training/SGD/gradients/dense_1/MatMul_grad/MatMul}}]]
```

I'm trying to solve a regression problem using Keras and a custom function provided by https://github.com/farrell236/DeepPose

The network is a quite simple CNN VGG-like.

I think the problem is the loss function. In particular, I suppose that the weight initialization is the issue (take a look at the Tensorflow example: https://github.com/farrell236/DeepPose/blob/master/tensorflow/example)

That's my loss function:

```py
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = SE3GeodesicLoss(np.ones((1, 6)))
    tf.initializers.constant([loss])

    y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, dtype=tf.float32)
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, dtype=tf.float32)

    loss = SE3GeodesicLoss(np.ones(6))
    geodesic_loss = loss.geodesic_loss(y_pred, y_true)
    geodesic_loss = tf.cast(geodesic_loss, dtype=tf.float32)

    return geodesic_loss
```

What's strange is that I'm able to use this function as a metric for the training.

Further information:
What I'm trying to do is to estimate the position of an object having images as input and relative Eulerian angles and distance of the target as labels  (which means 6 parameters [r_x, r_y, r_z, t_x, t_y, t_z]). I'm trying to implement this loss function in order to solve the attitude estimation problem. Other losses (means: MSE, MAE) are not effective enough in solving attitude regression problem.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. Without seeing the code you've used to build the model it's going to be really difficult for the community to recreate the issue and help you. Could you share a little more detail please?

Comment: Hi Stewart thank's for the advice. I'll try to furtherly clarify my issue by expanding my original post. You can find the net architecture at the following link: https://gist.github.com/mattiavarile/c9fdac3b20c18830eea8b1b85c477449